# What is the best way to copy storyboard from one app to another in ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am working on renovating my current `IOS` project architecture. To move storyboards, I copied the old `Main.Storyboard` and `LaunchScreen.StoryBoard` XML to new `Main.storyboard` and `LaunchScreen.StoryBoard` XML (Project name was the same).

I also Fixed the `localization` and `assets` linking part. Everything is fine, and after successfully building the project, `UI` is getting distorted in `iPhone 6` and other versions except to `iPhone 5`. I reconfirm the constraint with the old project, and there was no change.

The old app is working fine with different-different iPhone screen sizes. Is there any right way to copy the storyboard? Or Am I missing something here?

## Edit-1

I think `StoryBoard` layout size is limited to `iphone5` only.

Comment: you could copy and paste the storyboard file itself, that's how I've done it

Comment: @LukePatterson Will that make any difference to the autolayout? BTW let me try it

Comment: I did it a long time ago and everything was fine

Comment: @LukePatterson I tried but no help :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you did it is correct.  You're simply running into the fact that your layout constraints are either non-existant or wrong.  There's nothing magical about a storyboard...it's just a file like any other you'd copy into your new project.

You should probably select your toplevel view in each view controller and then tell Xcode to remove all the constraints and reset them to the suggested ones, and go from there.

Answer (score 7):

### Solution

[image]

Than browse your StoryBoardName.storyboard file.

That'll definitely work including all your constants .

> Note : make sure you check copy item if needed when you add you file to protect the original source file.

Comment: THANK YOU! Constraints all carried over when I did this in Xcode 8 just now.